# Why some packages in xenial have a higher version number than yakkety

Tags: apt, 16.04, upgrade

Why Some packages in Xenial have higher version number than on Yakkety.

for example mariadb version 10.0.27 on xenial, but version 10.0.25 in Yakkety. Even the 4.8 kernel has a higher version in xenial.

This is actually an issue, because many of the xenial package where not upgraded when upgrading 16.04 to 16.10. Because of that I had some inconsistencies.

I have 4.4% packages that are no longer downloadable, many are because the version in xenial is higher than Yakkety.

Comment: This sounds to me like a bug that should be reported. 10.0.27 should have been uploaded to Yakkety before being uploaded to Xenial.

Answer (score -1):

Since .deb files are version specific, it is probably because the developer hasn't compiled their code for your version of Ubuntu. It will probably be updated soon if it's a popular repository.
Good Luck!
- The Exp3rt